# CDS Pricing formula leads to negative prices

Tags: fixed-income, cds

I'm using this formula to price sovereign CDSs according to CDS Returns, Augustin, Saleh and Xu (2020), Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control.

[image]

As you can see, the highlighted part will become negative in the case the spread is lower than the coupon. I'm looking at 25bp coupon contracts, therefore prices often go negative.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you pls explain the terms in either side of the equation?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but I'll try. The standard running spread is what the protection buyer pays to the protection seller, e.g. 100 bps of the notional per year. If the quoted CDS spread, roughly equal to the Z-spread of the reference entity's bonds, is greater than the running spread, then the protection buyer pays an upfront fee to the protection seller. Conversely, if the CDS spread < running spread, then the protection buyer pays an upfront fee to the protection seller, but later receives the running spread.

Comment: Ok, so if you plug in the numbers in the formula we get a price for the CDS. Do you agree this price can be negative? If i'm to calculate the return vs yesterday's price, if the price is negative, don't you think this would be wrong?

Comment: Why is this wrong? Suppose, for example, you enter into a fix v float interest rate swap. At inception, it has zero value. Later, if you want to unwind later  the intetest rates may have gone up or down, the swap has some positive or negative value, and you'd pay or receive a fee to unwind it. What am I missing?

Comment: A swap is not an asset whose return you calculate by price divided by last price minus one. Digest Dimitri Vulis' second comment. What applies to interest rates swaps applies to credit default swaps as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the coupon c on the fixed leg, is higher than the spread, then the buyer could find cheaper insurance in the market. So it's entirely reasonable that the price would be negative.

Comment: What's a CDS coupon?

Comment: I mean the coupon rate c specified on the "fixed" leg of the swap. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: If you mean "running spread", please use industry standard terminology.

Comment: I'm using terminology lifted from the paper. c is the coupon specified in the swap contract (typically 100 or 500 bps) - The running spread would be $s_t$.

Comment: The paper https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2985213 does refer to "coupon" and also to "insurance", which hurts its credibility.

Comment: How so? I find their terminology quite unambiguous, and a CDS is typically understood as insurance against default.

Comment: https://www.ft.com/content/09aa387d-fe2d-397f-b22c-2a5387ab9a21

Comment: "default insurance" is a widely used term to describe the payments of a CDS. Whether or not it falls under the technical definition of "insurance" (as in requiring an insured interest) is besides the point.

Comment: https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d2/de0/class_quant_lib_1_1_credit_default_swap.html#af33e383fa73984d52114e0452f3bceb1